# Is there any word for a subject which we need not memorize?

Tags: single-word-requests

In a conversion, i was telling my friend about the importance of mathematics subject. I said that mathematics is a such subject which we do not need to memorize.

So, is there any word available to say that

> mathematics is not a ......(adjective) subject, like some others which must be learned "parrot-fashion"?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your question... Even after Ronan's edit of _memorizing_ to _memorize_, I would have to guess that _conversion_ is a _conversation, I wonder if "mathematics subject" is the whole of mathematics or a subject in the realm of mathematics, and what "subject like parrot" means, I really don't know (I know what _to parrot_ something is, but you _seem_ to be looking for the _opposite_ of that in which case the word on the dots could be **not**. Its would still not create a grammatical sentence though. I suggest you have a look at [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Ell, somebody edited it. i edit again.

Comment: I'm not ELL :) There are a lot of edits going on, still there are remaining errors and unclear things :) In your question title you now ask for the opposite of what should be on the dots... Please clarify :)

Comment: V.K. about your other question ... If your question is really "What do you call someone who laughs in a situation where most people would become annoyed or be serious" then you should ask it either here or on the ELL SE site, but first check this answer at [cognitive sciences SE](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/3957/why-do-people-laugh-in-serious-situations).

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you mean to say

> Mathematics is not a subject that is simply ***rote learning***

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rote+learning

Answer (score 2):

I think the characteristic of *mathematics* that OP has in mind is that it's an extreme example of a...

> [***Hard*** science (as opposed to "soft" sciences)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_and_soft_science)

In actual fact, *physics* is more often cited as [*the ultimate hard science*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22are%20ends%20in%20themselves%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=physics%20%22the%20ultimate%20hard%20science%22&tbm=bks), but here's my position...

[image]

To my mind, the key difference is that a typical **soft** science tends to include things based on *opinions* or *morality* (which you have to *learn*). In the middle ground, most scientific fields are more concerned with things you can *measure*. But in practice this may be extremely difficult, so you often end up having to learn/remember what someone else already measured.

When we come to *mathematics*, it is true that most of us actually did "learn" that, say, **π** = 3.142 (or however many significant digits our teacher arbitrarily decided were appropriate). But any "real" mathematician could simply ***calculate*** the value - he doesn't need to *learn/memorise* it.

---

As a rule, most knowledge contained within **hard** science (and pure maths in particular) can be derived from *first principles*. In mathematics the first principles are formally referred to as [axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom). Consider the statement *"It's axiomatic that [some fact]"*. For most of us, *axioms* are things which are so obvious we don't need to "learn" them.

In case it's not obvious, *hard* here has nothing to do with *difficulty*. It's the sense applicable in expressions like [***hard*** facts and figures](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22some%20hard%20figures%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) *(actual, definite, not arbitrary or made up)*.

Comment: +1 just for including XKCD alone, and another one (if I could) for the answer itself. Still, the XKCD +1 is more important, so that’s the one you’re getting; you’ll have to get the content-based +1 from someone else. ;-)

Comment: @Janus: I'm not so sure it wasn't *you* who previously posted a link to that particular XKCD example. I *am* sure I only answered this question in the first place because I remember first coming across it through a link on ELU.

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

> *Math is not a [**rote**](http://thesaurus.com/browse/rote?__utma=1.886595391.1363165734.1400047986.1400064604.551&__utmb=1.6.8.1400064628958&__utmc=1&__utmx=-&__utmz=1.1400047986.550.486.utmcsr=google|utmccn=%28organic%29|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=%28not%20provided%29&__utmv=-&__utmk=86927640)
>   (learning) subject*.
>
> **rote**: proceeding mechanically or repetitiously.

Answer (score 0):

> To mug up.

I don't know if it is true for mathematics but I can tell what you are looking for , e.g-

> He gets full marks in theory subjects as he mugs up his books.

Or if a teacher tells a student:

> I don't want you to mug up the syllabus , I want to make you understand it.

Comment: From the limited understanding I have of the question, it seems that the OP is looking for a completely different concept. Although  "I want to make you _understand_ it" actually _might_ be the right answer!

Comment: I know right our accountancy teacher always use the two words two differentiate between maths and accounts :D

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are saying that mathematic is a subject that can not  , rather than need not , be memorised.  The adjective that can fit you sentence in this case should be [memorizable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/memorize?q=memorizable#memorize__15).

Answer (score 0):

I think for the example of what mathematics **is not** the best word is *rote*, as Neil and Elian recommend. But to answer the question in the title (namely, "a word for a subject we need not memorize") about what mathematics **is** I would like to suggest [*dialectical*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dialectic):

> of, pertaining to, or of the nature of logical argumentation.

In trying to discover what justice is, Socrates and his interlocutors construct an idealized city in Plato's *Republic*. In their discussion the question of education comes up, and mathematics is extolled "if a man practices it for the sake of coming to know and not for trade" (525d).

Socrates sees mathematics in particular as a means to pursuing the truth:

> "For all the other arts are directed to human opinions and desires, or to generation and composition, or to the care of what is grown or put together. And as for the rest, those that we said do lay hold of something of what is--geometry and the arts following on it--we observe that they do dream about what *is*..." (533b).

And he pairs it with studies that guide a student to understanding:

> "... the study of calculation and geometry and all the preparatory education required for dialectic must be put before them as children..." (536d).

The *dialectic* Socrates is referring to is defined here:

> "...when a man tries by discussion--by means of argument without the use of any of the senses--to attain to each thing itself that *is* and doesn't give up before he grasps by intellection itself that which is good itself.... Don't you call this journey dialectic?" (532b).

(Because of the similarity between this definition and mathematical reasoning, Socrates might even consider one a type of the other.)

In use, one might say:

> Mathematics is *dialectical (in the Platonic/Socratic sense)*, unlike some other fields whose material must be learned by rote.

I strongly recommend using the parenthetical phrase, because it will help listeners familiar with philosophy hone into your meaning. Especially those who know of Plato's [*Meno*](http://www.classicreader.com/book/1790/4/), in which Socrates helps an uneducated slave derive a geometrical idea. Socrates asserts that the slave had always known the idea; the idea "only [needed] to be awakened into knowledge by putting questions to him" and not through memorization.